# Rain pants for tall people

Tags: clothing, rain-gear, pants

I've been looking for a rain pants for myself.
My attention was caught by [Outdoor Research Paladin Pants](http://www.outdoorresearch.com/en/or-gear/pants/mens-paladin-pants.html).
These have side zips which are really great.
The problem is: it comes in regular fit only and I'm 183 cm (6 feet) and weigh only 65 kg (143 pounds). I simply don't fit in their size table. It is either too short or too ample at waistline.

My question is: is there a manufacturer that makes those kind of pants for people of my proportions? Thank you.

Comment: It might be easier to answer your question if you include a specific waist and inseam size; I'm guessing about 28-29 x 33?

Comment: It is 30 by 33.

Comment: There are several size small 32-inch inseam rain pants [listed on REI.com](http://www.rei.com/search?cat=40005464&cat=40004586&jxSize=S&hist=cat%2C40005464%3AMen%27s+Pants^cat%2C40004586%3AMen%27s+Rain+Pants^jxSize%2CS) so that should at least get you close.  If you prefer a 34-inch inseam the closest I have yet found is [this REI pant in medium](http://www.rei.com/product/794212/rei-ultra-light-pants-mens-34-inseam).

Comment: Wow, those are expensive! 8-O

Comment: FWIW, I've started collecting my notes on backpacking gear for the very tall: http://ultratall-ultralight.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several size small 32-inch inseam rain pants [listed on REI.com](http://www.rei.com/search?cat=40005464&cat=40004586&jxSize=S&hist=cat,40005464%3aMen%27s%20Pants%5Ecat,40004586%3aMen%27s%20Rain%20Pants%5EjxSize,S) so that should at least get you close. If you prefer a 34-inch inseam the closest I have yet found is [this REI pant](http://www.rei.com/product/794212/rei-ultra-light-pants-mens-34-inseam) in medium.

You found the expensive Arc'Teryx Beta AR in the right size at [Mountain Gear](http://www.mountaingear.com/webstore//Clothing/Beta-AR-Pant-Men-s-Long-Length/_/R-220539.htm?voucherCode=98151).

Comment: There are expensive. But at least they do exist. Maybe I'll manage to find something less pricy.